# Python encoding over unicode strings

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, ascii

So in a python terminal I type the following:

```
>>> s = "γειά"       ## it just means 'hi' in Greek
>>> s
'\x9a\x9c\xa0\xe1'   ## What is this? - Is it utf-encoding? Is it ascii escaped?
>>> print s
γειά
```

and now the fun part:

```
>>> a = u"γειά"
>>> a
u'\u03b3\u03b5\u03b9\u03ac'    # Again what is this? utf-8 encoded? If so, how?
>>> print a
γειά
```

I am totally confused over encodings and particularly on utf-8 encoded strings and/or ascii encoded strings. What would be the difference between the above 2 snippets and how do they tie-in the unicode function?

```
>>> result = unicode(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 0: ordinal
                     not in range(128)

>>> result = unicode(s, 'utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 0: invalid s
                     tart byte
```

Could someone explain to me what's happening here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: An obligatorty [Joel link](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: See also: [Pragmatic Unicode or How Do I Stop the Pain?](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) which covers many of the same points as the Joel article, plus some more regarding how to actually solve these problems.

Answer (score 2):

On your first attempt you're seeing the *encoded* version of the string, and not in utf-8 at all:

```
>>> s='\x9a\x9c\xa0\xe1'
>>> s.decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 0: invalid start byte
```

It is encoding in whatever encode your shell is using.

On your second example, you're creating an `unicode` string. Python, armed with your shell encoding, is able to decode it from the input and store it as *unicode codepoints* (`\u03b3\u03b5\u03b9\u03ac`). Later, when you `print` it, Python also knows your shell's encoding and is able to *encode it* from `unicode` to actual bytes.

About your third example, you're using [`unicode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?#unicode) function explicitly. Which when used without an encoding as argument, it will use `ascii` as default. As there's no way `ascii` support Greek characters, Python is complaining about that.

Bottom line, you need to know what encoding your console is using to figure out exactly what Python is doing with your code. If you are on Windows you can do this with `chcp` command. On Linux you can use `locale` command.

Of course I forgot the most important advice ever :P. As @thg435 suggested this is a **must read**: [Unicode by Joel](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Also is worth mentioning that a lot of these changes dramatically in Python 3.

Comment: *It is probably encoding in whatever encode your shell is using*. It most definitely is.

Comment: Yes haha, sometimes I found it hard to be _definitive_ about my conclusions :)